# Why can't I connect to a Notion page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, notion-api

I am using [notion-sdk-py](https://github.com/ramnes/notion-sdk-py). But when I'm trying to connect to a [page](https://www.notion.so/9e8f03199daf4a73a9001a2afcab9450?v=ce96bfaad03f4f599b01980c35d81cdc), I'm getting an error:

> notion_client.errors.APIResponseError: Could not find database with
> ID: 9e8f0319-9daf-4a73-a900-1a2afcab9450. Make sure the relevant pages
> and databases are shared with your integration.

My code:

```
from notion_client import Client
from notion_client.helpers import collect_paginated_api

notion = Client(auth="secret_#################")
list_users_response = notion.users.list()
print(list_users_response)

all_results = collect_paginated_api(
    notion.databases.query, database_id="9e8f03199daf4a73a9001a2afcab9450"
)
```

The code should be getting all cards from that page.

Comment: seems like a wrong API KEY

Comment: api key is ok, print(list_users_response) worked

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar issue while working with Notion API integrations.

To get API access to a specific database, you must first explicitly share that database (or element above) with your integration. Unfortunately, this option is not available during the token creation process but instructions can be found in the [documentation](https://developers.notion.com/docs/working-with-databases).

Here are the steps to share a database with your integration:

1. Open the desired database in full-screen view within Notion.
2. Click on the three-dot menu (•••) located at the top-right corner of the page.
3. Select "Add connections" from the menu.
4. Choose your integration from the list.

Please note that sharing access operates on a hierarchical recursive basis. This means that if you grant access to an integration for a container that houses multiple databases, all databases within that container will be accessible by the integration.